# Progress bar circle should start filling up when visible on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would to start progress bar circle animation only when screen visible.
But what I want they should Do start filling up while they are visible on screen

```
<div class="card-option">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="c100 p35 big orange">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="fill"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

script

```
$(function() {
  $(".c100").each(function() {
    $(this)
    .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
    .width(0)
    .animate({
    width: $(this).data("origWidth")
    }, 1200);
  });

});
```

[link Demo](https://codepen.io/hesham-farag/pen/PjNaxM)

Comment: I can't reproduce any issue with just that code.

Comment: Louys .. what did you mean

Answer (score 1):

**Try this Code**

add `transition` to `.c100 .bar` class

```
transition: transform 1s;
```

```js
$(function() {
    $(".c100").each(function(index) {  
            $(this)
        .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
        .width(0)
        .animate({
            width: $(this).data("origWidth")
        }, 1200);
        (function($this, i) { 
            var t = setTimeout(function() { 
                $($this).children().find('.bar').addClass('fix');
            }, 1500);
        })(this, index);
    });
    
});
```

```css
.rect-auto,
.c100.p65 .slice,
.c100.p100 .slice {
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}
.pie,
.c100 .bar,
.c100.p65 .fill,
.c100.p100 .fill {
  position: absolute;
  border: 0.08em solid #307bbb;
  width: 0.84em;
  height: 0.84em;
  clip: rect(0em, 0.5em, 1em, 0em);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.pie-fill,
.c100.p65 .fill,
.c100.p100 .fill {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.c100 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 120px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
.c100 *,
.c100 *:before,
.c100 *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.c100.center {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.c100.big {
  font-size: 120px;
}
.c100.small {
  font-size: 80px;
}
.c100 > span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 5em;
  line-height: 5em;
  font-size: 0.2em;
  color: #cccccc;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.c100:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.08em;
  left: 0.08em;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 0.84em;
  height: 0.84em;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}
.c100 .slice {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  clip: rect(0em, 1em, 1em, 0.5em);
}
.c100.p1 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3.6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3.6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3.6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3.6deg);
  transform: rotate(3.6deg);
}
.c100.p2 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(7.2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(7.2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(7.2deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(7.2deg);
  transform: rotate(7.2deg);
}
.c100.p3 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(10.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(10.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(10.8deg);
  transform: rotate(10.8deg);
}
.c100.p4 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(14.4deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(14.4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(14.4deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(14.4deg);
  transform: rotate(14.4deg);
}
.c100.p5 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(18deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(18deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(18deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(18deg);
  transform: rotate(18deg);
}
.c100.p6 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(21.6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(21.6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(21.6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(21.6deg);
  transform: rotate(21.6deg);
}
.c100.p7 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(25.2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(25.2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(25.2deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(25.2deg);
  transform: rotate(25.2deg);
}
.c100.p8 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(28.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(28.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(28.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(28.8deg);
  transform: rotate(28.8deg);
}
.c100.p9 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(32.4deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(32.4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(32.4deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(32.4deg);
  transform: rotate(32.4deg);
}
.c100.p10 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(36deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(36deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(36deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(36deg);
  transform: rotate(36deg);
}
.c100.p11 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(39.6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(39.6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(39.6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(39.6deg);
  transform: rotate(39.6deg);
}
.c100.p12 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(43.2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(43.2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(43.2deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(43.2deg);
  transform: rotate(43.2deg);
}
.c100.p13 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(46.800000000000004deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(46.800000000000004deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(46.800000000000004deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(46.800000000000004deg);
  transform: rotate(46.800000000000004deg);
}
.c100.p14 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(50.4deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(50.4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(50.4deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(50.4deg);
  transform: rotate(50.4deg);
}
.c100.p15 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(54deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(54deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(54deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(54deg);
  transform: rotate(54deg);
}
.c100.p16 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(57.6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(57.6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(57.6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(57.6deg);
  transform: rotate(57.6deg);
}
.c100.p17 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(61.2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(61.2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(61.2deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(61.2deg);
  transform: rotate(61.2deg);
}
.c100.p18 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(64.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(64.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(64.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(64.8deg);
  transform: rotate(64.8deg);
}
.c100.p19 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(68.4deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(68.4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(68.4deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(68.4deg);
  transform: rotate(68.4deg);
}
.c100.p20 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(72deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(72deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(72deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(72deg);
  transform: rotate(72deg);
}
.c100.p21 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(75.60000000000001deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(75.60000000000001deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(75.60000000000001deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(75.60000000000001deg);
  transform: rotate(75.60000000000001deg);
}
.c100.p22 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(79.2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(79.2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(79.2deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(79.2deg);
  transform: rotate(79.2deg);
}
.c100.p23 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(82.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(82.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(82.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(82.8deg);
  transform: rotate(82.8deg);
}
.c100.p24 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(86.4deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(86.4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(86.4deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(86.4deg);
  transform: rotate(86.4deg);
}
.c100.p25 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.c100.p26 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(93.60000000000001deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(93.60000000000001deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(93.60000000000001deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(93.60000000000001deg);
  transform: rotate(93.60000000000001deg);
}
.c100.p27 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(97.2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(97.2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(97.2deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(97.2deg);
  transform: rotate(97.2deg);
}
.c100.p28 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(100.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(100.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(100.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(100.8deg);
  transform: rotate(100.8deg);
}
.c100.p29 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(104.4deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(104.4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(104.4deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(104.4deg);
  transform: rotate(104.4deg);
}
.c100.p30 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(108deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(108deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(108deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(108deg);
  transform: rotate(108deg);
}
.c100.p31 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(111.60000000000001deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(111.60000000000001deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(111.60000000000001deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(111.60000000000001deg);
  transform: rotate(111.60000000000001deg);
}
.c100.p32 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(115.2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(115.2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(115.2deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(115.2deg);
  transform: rotate(115.2deg);
}
.c100.p33 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(118.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(118.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(118.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(118.8deg);
  transform: rotate(118.8deg);
}
.c100.p34 .bar .fill{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(122.4deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(122.4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(122.4deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(122.4deg);
  transform: rotate(122.4deg);
}
.c100.p35 .bar.fix {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(126deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(126deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(126deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(126deg);
  transform: rotate(126deg);
}
.c100.p36 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(129.6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(129.6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(129.6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(129.6deg);
  transform: rotate(129.6deg);
}
.c100.p37 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(133.20000000000002deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(133.20000000000002deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(133.20000000000002deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(133.20000000000002deg);
  transform: rotate(133.20000000000002deg);
}
.c100.p38 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(136.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(136.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(136.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(136.8deg);
  transform: rotate(136.8deg);
}
.c100.p39 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(140.4deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(140.4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(140.4deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(140.4deg);
  transform: rotate(140.4deg);
}
.c100.p40 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(144deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(144deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(144deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(144deg);
  transform: rotate(144deg);
}
.c100.p41 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(147.6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(147.6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(147.6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(147.6deg);
  transform: rotate(147.6deg);
}
.c100.p42 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(151.20000000000002deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(151.20000000000002deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(151.20000000000002deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(151.20000000000002deg);
  transform: rotate(151.20000000000002deg);
}
.c100.p43 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(154.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(154.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(154.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(154.8deg);
  transform: rotate(154.8deg);
}
.c100.p44 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(158.4deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(158.4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(158.4deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(158.4deg);
  transform: rotate(158.4deg);
}
.c100.p45 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(162deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(162deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(162deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(162deg);
  transform: rotate(162deg);
}
.c100.p46 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(165.6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(165.6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(165.6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(165.6deg);
  transform: rotate(165.6deg);
}
.c100.p47 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(169.20000000000002deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(169.20000000000002deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(169.20000000000002deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(169.20000000000002deg);
  transform: rotate(169.20000000000002deg);
}
.c100.p48 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(172.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(172.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(172.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(172.8deg);
  transform: rotate(172.8deg);
}
.c100.p49 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(176.4deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(176.4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(176.4deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(176.4deg);
  transform: rotate(176.4deg);
}
.c100.p50 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.c100.p51 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(183.6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(183.6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(183.6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(183.6deg);
  transform: rotate(183.6deg);
}
.c100.p52 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(187.20000000000002deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(187.20000000000002deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(187.20000000000002deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(187.20000000000002deg);
  transform: rotate(187.20000000000002deg);
}
.c100.p53 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(190.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(190.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(190.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(190.8deg);
  transform: rotate(190.8deg);
}
.c100.p54 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(194.4deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(194.4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(194.4deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(194.4deg);
  transform: rotate(194.4deg);
}
.c100.p55 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(198deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(198deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(198deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(198deg);
  transform: rotate(198deg);
}
.c100.p56 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(201.6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(201.6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(201.6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(201.6deg);
  transform: rotate(201.6deg);
}
.c100.p57 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(205.20000000000002deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(205.20000000000002deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(205.20000000000002deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(205.20000000000002deg);
  transform: rotate(205.20000000000002deg);
}
.c100.p58 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(208.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(208.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(208.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(208.8deg);
  transform: rotate(208.8deg);
}
.c100.p59 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(212.4deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(212.4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(212.4deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(212.4deg);
  transform: rotate(212.4deg);
}
.c100.p60 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(216deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(216deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(216deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(216deg);
  transform: rotate(216deg);
}
.c100.p61 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(219.6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(219.6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(219.6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(219.6deg);
  transform: rotate(219.6deg);
}
.c100.p62 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(223.20000000000002deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(223.20000000000002deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(223.20000000000002deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(223.20000000000002deg);
  transform: rotate(223.20000000000002deg);
}
.c100.p63 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(226.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(226.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(226.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(226.8deg);
  transform: rotate(226.8deg);
}
.c100.p64 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(230.4deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(230.4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(230.4deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(230.4deg);
  transform: rotate(230.4deg);
}
.c100.p65 .bar.fix {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(234deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(234deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(234deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(234deg);
  transform: rotate(234deg);
}
.c100.p66 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(237.6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(237.6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(237.6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(237.6deg);
  transform: rotate(237.6deg);
}
.c100.p67 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(241.20000000000002deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(241.20000000000002deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(241.20000000000002deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(241.20000000000002deg);
  transform: rotate(241.20000000000002deg);
}
.c100.p68 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(244.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(244.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(244.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(244.8deg);
  transform: rotate(244.8deg);
}
.c100.p69 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(248.4deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(248.4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(248.4deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(248.4deg);
  transform: rotate(248.4deg);
}
.c100.p70 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(252deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(252deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(252deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(252deg);
  transform: rotate(252deg);
}
.c100.p71 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(255.6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(255.6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(255.6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(255.6deg);
  transform: rotate(255.6deg);
}
.c100.p72 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(259.2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(259.2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(259.2deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(259.2deg);
  transform: rotate(259.2deg);
}
.c100.p73 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(262.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(262.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(262.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(262.8deg);
  transform: rotate(262.8deg);
}
.c100.p74 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(266.40000000000003deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(266.40000000000003deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(266.40000000000003deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(266.40000000000003deg);
  transform: rotate(266.40000000000003deg);
}
.c100.p75 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.c100.p76 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(273.6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(273.6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(273.6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(273.6deg);
  transform: rotate(273.6deg);
}
.c100.p77 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(277.2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(277.2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(277.2deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(277.2deg);
  transform: rotate(277.2deg);
}
.c100.p78 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(280.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(280.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(280.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(280.8deg);
  transform: rotate(280.8deg);
}
.c100.p79 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(284.40000000000003deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(284.40000000000003deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(284.40000000000003deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(284.40000000000003deg);
  transform: rotate(284.40000000000003deg);
}
.c100.p80 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(288deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(288deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(288deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(288deg);
  transform: rotate(288deg);
}
.c100.p81 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(291.6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(291.6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(291.6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(291.6deg);
  transform: rotate(291.6deg);
}
.c100.p82 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(295.2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(295.2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(295.2deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(295.2deg);
  transform: rotate(295.2deg);
}
.c100.p83 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(298.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(298.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(298.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(298.8deg);
  transform: rotate(298.8deg);
}
.c100.p84 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(302.40000000000003deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(302.40000000000003deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(302.40000000000003deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(302.40000000000003deg);
  transform: rotate(302.40000000000003deg);
}
.c100.p85 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(306deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(306deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(306deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(306deg);
  transform: rotate(306deg);
}
.c100.p86 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(309.6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(309.6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(309.6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(309.6deg);
  transform: rotate(309.6deg);
}
.c100.p87 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(313.2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(313.2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(313.2deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(313.2deg);
  transform: rotate(313.2deg);
}
.c100.p88 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(316.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(316.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(316.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(316.8deg);
  transform: rotate(316.8deg);
}
.c100.p89 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(320.40000000000003deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(320.40000000000003deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(320.40000000000003deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(320.40000000000003deg);
  transform: rotate(320.40000000000003deg);
}
.c100.p90 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(324deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(324deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(324deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(324deg);
  transform: rotate(324deg);
}
.c100.p91 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(327.6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(327.6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(327.6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(327.6deg);
  transform: rotate(327.6deg);
}
.c100.p92 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(331.2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(331.2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(331.2deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(331.2deg);
  transform: rotate(331.2deg);
}
.c100.p93 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(334.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(334.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(334.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(334.8deg);
  transform: rotate(334.8deg);
}
.c100.p94 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(338.40000000000003deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(338.40000000000003deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(338.40000000000003deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(338.40000000000003deg);
  transform: rotate(338.40000000000003deg);
}
.c100.p95 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(342deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(342deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(342deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(342deg);
  transform: rotate(342deg);
}
.c100.p96 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(345.6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(345.6deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(345.6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(345.6deg);
  transform: rotate(345.6deg);
}
.c100.p97 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(349.2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(349.2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(349.2deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(349.2deg);
  transform: rotate(349.2deg);
}
.c100.p98 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(352.8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(352.8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(352.8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(352.8deg);
  transform: rotate(352.8deg);
}
.c100.p99 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(356.40000000000003deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(356.40000000000003deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(356.40000000000003deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(356.40000000000003deg);
  transform: rotate(356.40000000000003deg);
}
.c100.p100 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
.c100:hover {
  cursor: default;
}
.c100:hover > span {
width: 4.33em;
line-height: 4.33em;
font-size: 28px;
  color: #307bbb;
}
.c100:hover:after {
  top: 0.04em;
  left: 0.04em;
  width: 0.92em;
  height: 0.92em;
}
.c100.dark {
  background-color: #777777;
}
.c100.dark .bar,
.c100.dark .fill {
  border-color: #c6ff00 !important;
}
.c100.dark > span {
  color: #777777;
}
.c100.dark:after {
  background-color: #666666;
}
.c100.dark:hover > span {
  color: #c6ff00;
}
.c100.green .bar,
.c100.green .fill {
  border-color: #4db53c !important;
}
.c100.green:hover > span {
  color: #4db53c;
}
.c100.green.dark .bar,
.c100.green.dark .fill {
  border-color: #5fd400 !important;
}
.c100.green.dark:hover > span {
  color: #5fd400;
}
.c100.orange .bar,
.c100.orange .fill {
  border-color: #ff5e3a !important;
}
.c100.orange:hover > span {
  color: #ff5e3a;
}
.c100.orange.dark .bar,
.c100.orange.dark .fill {
  border-color: #e08833 !important;
}
.c100.orange.dark:hover > span {
  color: #e08833;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-option">
  <div class="card-header"> 
    <div class="c100 p35 big orange">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="fill"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card-option">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="c100 p65 big orange">
     
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="fill"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: i added could you please look at to code      https://codepen.io/hesham-farag/pen/PjNaxM

Comment: see this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/weWdbw  You should apply `transition` for `transform` that is for `.bar` class(in css) and just add class `fix` to every `.c100.p .bar` class eg:`.c100.p2 .bar.fix`(in css),since we are adding `fix` class using timeout function.Hope its clear.

Answer (score 1):

i get the resolve in the blow link .. thank you for all

https://codepen.io/hesham-farag/pen/WOxbed

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('.data-one').circliful();
        $('.data-two').circliful();
        $('.data-three').circliful();
    });

(function ($) {

    $.fn.circliful = function (options, callback) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            startdegree: 0,
            fgcolor: "#556b2f",
            bgcolor: "#eee",
            fill: false,
            width: 15,
            dimension: 200,
            fontsize: 15,
            percent: 50,
            animationstep: 1.0,
            iconsize: '20px',
            iconcolor: '#999',
            border: 'default',
            complete: null,
            bordersize: 10
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {

            var customSettings = ["fgcolor", "bgcolor", "fill", "width", "dimension", "fontsize", "animationstep", "endPercent", "icon", "iconcolor", "iconsize", "border", "startdegree", "bordersize"];

            var customSettingsObj = {};
            var icon = '';
            var percent;
            var endPercent = 0;
            var obj = $(this);
            var fill = false;
            var text, info;

            obj.addClass('circliful');

            checkDataAttributes(obj);

            if (obj.data('text') != undefined) {
                text = obj.data('text');

                if (obj.data('icon') != undefined) {
                    icon = $('<i></i>')
                        .addClass('fa ' + $(this).data('icon'))
                        .css({
                            'color': customSettingsObj.iconcolor,
                            'font-size': customSettingsObj.iconsize
                        });
                }

                if (obj.data('type') != undefined) {
                    type = $(this).data('type');

                    if (type == 'half') {
                        addCircleText(obj, 'circle-text-half', (customSettingsObj.dimension / 1.45));
                    } else {
                        addCircleText(obj, 'circle-text', customSettingsObj.dimension);
                    }
                } else {
                    addCircleText(obj, 'circle-text', customSettingsObj.dimension);
                }
            }

            if ($(this).data("total") != undefined && $(this).data("part") != undefined) {
                var total = $(this).data("total") / 100;

                percent = (($(this).data("part") / total) / 100).toFixed(3);
                endPercent = ($(this).data("part") / total).toFixed(3);
            } else {
                if ($(this).data("percent") != undefined) {
                    percent = $(this).data("percent") / 100;
                    endPercent = $(this).data("percent");
                } else {
                    percent = settings.percent / 100;
                }
            }

            if ($(this).data('info') != undefined) {
                info = $(this).data('info');

                if ($(this).data('type') != undefined) {
                    type = $(this).data('type');

                    if (type == 'half') {
                        addInfoText(obj, 0.9);
                    } else {
                        addInfoText(obj, 1.25);
                    }
                } else {
                    addInfoText(obj, 1.25);
                }
            }

            $(this).width(customSettingsObj.dimension + 'px');

            var size = customSettingsObj.dimension,
                canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>').attr({
                    width: size,
                    height: size
                }).appendTo($(this)).get(0);

            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
            if ( dpr ) {
                var $canvas = $(canvas);
                $canvas.css('width', size);
                $canvas.css('height', size);
                $canvas.attr('width', size * dpr);
                $canvas.attr('height', size * dpr);

                context.scale(dpr, dpr);
            }

            var container = $(canvas).parent();
            var x = size / 2;
            var y = size / 2;
            var degrees = customSettingsObj.percent * 360.0;
            var radians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
            var radius = size / 2.5;
            var startAngle = 2.3 * Math.PI;
            var endAngle = 0;
            var counterClockwise = false;
            var curPerc = customSettingsObj.animationstep === 0.0 ? endPercent : 0.0;
            var curStep = Math.max(customSettingsObj.animationstep, 0.0);
            var circ = Math.PI * 2;
            var quart = Math.PI / 2;
            var type = '';
            var fireCallback = true;
            var additionalAngelPI = (customSettingsObj.startdegree / 180) * Math.PI;

            if ($(this).data('type') != undefined) {
                type = $(this).data('type');

                if (type == 'half') {
                    startAngle = 2.0 * Math.PI;
                    endAngle = 3.13;
                    circ = Math.PI;
                    quart = Math.PI / 0.996;
                }
            }

            if ($(this).data('type') != undefined) {
                type = $(this).data('type');

                if (type == 'angle') {
                    startAngle = 2.25 * Math.PI;
                    endAngle = 2.4;
                    circ = 1.53 + Math.PI;
                    quart = 0.73 + Math.PI / 0.996;
                }
            }

            /**
             * adds text to circle
             *
             * @param obj
             * @param cssClass
             * @param lineHeight
             */
            function addCircleText(obj, cssClass, lineHeight) {
                $("<span></span>")
                    .appendTo(obj)
                    .addClass(cssClass)
                    .html(text)
                    .prepend(icon)
                    .css({
                        'line-height': lineHeight + 'px',
                        'font-size': customSettingsObj.fontsize + 'px'
                    });
            }

            /**
             * adds info text to circle
             *
             * @param obj
             * @param factor
             */
            function addInfoText(obj, factor) {
                $('<span></span>')
                    .appendTo(obj)
                    .addClass('circle-info-half')
                    .css(
                        'line-height', (customSettingsObj.dimension * factor) + 'px'
                    )
                    .text(info);
            }

            /**
             * checks which data attributes are defined
             * @param obj
             */
            function checkDataAttributes(obj) {
                $.each(customSettings, function (index, attribute) {
                    if (obj.data(attribute) != undefined) {
                        customSettingsObj[attribute] = obj.data(attribute);
                    } else {
                        customSettingsObj[attribute] = $(settings).attr(attribute);
                    }

                    if (attribute == 'fill' && obj.data('fill') != undefined) {
                        fill = true;
                    }
                });
            }

            /**
             * animate foreground circle
             * @param current
             */
            function animate(current) {

                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(x, y, radius, endAngle, startAngle, false);

                context.lineWidth = customSettingsObj.width + 1;

                context.strokeStyle = customSettingsObj.bgcolor;
                context.stroke();

                if (fill) {
                    context.fillStyle = customSettingsObj.fill;
                    context.fill();
                }

                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(x, y, radius, -(quart) + additionalAngelPI, ((circ) * current) - quart + additionalAngelPI, false);

                if (customSettingsObj.border == 'outline') {
                    context.lineWidth = customSettingsObj.width + 13;
                } else if (customSettingsObj.border == 'inline') {
                    context.lineWidth = customSettingsObj.width - 13;
                }

                context.strokeStyle = customSettingsObj.fgcolor;
                context.stroke();

                if (curPerc < endPercent) {
                    curPerc += curStep;
                    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                        animate(Math.min(curPerc, endPercent) / 100);
                    }, obj);
                }

                if (curPerc == endPercent && fireCallback && typeof(options) != "undefined") {
                    if ($.isFunction(options.complete)) {
                        options.complete();

                        fireCallback = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            animate(curPerc / 100);

        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```